# I want to download many Files of same file extension with either Wget or Python, from a given Website Link

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I would like to download Files of the same File types .utu and .zip from the Following Microsoft Flight Simulator AI Traffic Websites :-

http://web.archive.org/web/20050315112710/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/acfiles.php?cat=6 *(Current Repaints)

http://web.archive.org/web/20050315112940/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/acfiles.php?cat=1 (Vintage Repaints)

On each of those pages there are Subcatagories for Airbus Boeing etc for the AI Aircraft types, and the repaints .zip Files choices are shown when you click on the Aircraft image.

The Folder name then becomes http://web.archive.org/web/20041114195147/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/repaints.php?ac=number&cat=(number) Then when you click the downloads repaints.php? becomes download.php?fileid=(4 digit number)

What do I need to type to download all the .zip Files at once ? As clicking on them individually to download would take ages.

Also I would like to download all .utu File extension File, For Flight 1 ultimate Traffic AI Aircraft repaints. from the Following Webpage :-

http://web.archive.org/web/20060512161232/http://ultimatetraffic.flight1.net:80/utfiles.asp?mode=1&index=0

Then When you click to download the Ultimate Traffic Aircraft Texture :- The last Folder Path becomes /utfiles.asp?mode=download&id=F1AIRepaintNumbers-Numbers-Numbers.utu And I would like to do the same as for the other Websites.

I used the following written code in Python 2.79, found on a video on Youtube, inserting my info to achieve my aim, but it unsurprisingly didn't work when I ran it timeouts and errors etc, probably due to it's simplicity :-

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import wget

def download_links(url):

source_code = requests.get(url)

plain_text = source_code.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):

href = link.get('href')

print(href)

wget.download(href)

download_links('http://web.archive.org/web/20041225023002/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/acfiles.php?cat=6')
```

Comment: I've figured out 90% of a script that works, but downloading the zip file format is still not working yet, will update

Comment: Hi Dave, I posted the same question, on the python.org forum. Here is the link to the Thread I created :- https://python-forum.io/Thread-I-Want-To-Download-Many-Files-Of-Same-File-Extension-With-Either-Wget-Or-Python, as you can see a code solution which worked, was found for one of the weblinks. But no response from the person who helped, me about the other Website Links  download query. Many thanks for your reply. Eddie

Comment: cool glad to hear you got a solution

Comment: Would you be able to help me Dave ?

Comment: Sure I'd be happy to try and help. The part I am working on now is saving the ZIP file format, but it's not working yet.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Dave thanks.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have just received this code (A hint) he says he doesn't normally do requests in that forum section, I hope this helps you :-Python Code: (Double-click to select all)
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
import requests
 
file_id = [6082, 6177]
for _id in file_id:
    a_zip = 'http://web.archive.org/web/20041108074847/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/download.php?file_id={}'.format(_id)
    with open('{}.zip'.format(_id), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(a_zip).content)

Comment: Hi Dave, I have just received a partial code (A hint) from the man in question, he says he doesn't normally do requests in that forum section, I hope this helps you :- just scroll down on page 2 of the Website link, I provided for you before. ignore the previous message, as you can see it hasn't displayed properly.

Comment: Hey Eddie, thanks for the update. I'll try using that hint and update you as I progress.

Comment: btw, are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: Python Version 3.4.3

Comment: Hi Dave, I am going to bed now, as its 1.20 am in the UK, I will contact you tomorrow. Are you in the USA ?

Comment: Ok Eddie, sorry for the delay. Yes I'm in USA about 8 hours earlier here. Will hopefully have progress for your tomorrow

Comment: Hi Dave, how are you getting on with the coding ?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I think I've got a version working, just cleaning it up now.

Comment: Marvelous thankyou so much Dave.

Comment: code in answer, run it in a directory to save the zip files. Open cmd in the directory `python3 the_script.py`

Comment: Thankyou very much Dave, I appreciate you helping me, taking so much time on the coding.

Comment: It's incomplete currently only works on one page, but that can be added one you get the basics working

Answer (score 1):

Update: Try this update, it should now download all zip files from all links on the first page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, zipfile, io

def get_zips(zips_page):
    # print(zips_page)
    zips_source = requests.get(zips_page).text
    zip_soup = BeautifulSoup(zips_source, "html.parser")
    for zip_file in zip_soup.select("a[href*=download.php?fileid=]"):
        zip_url = link_root + zip_file['href']
        print('downloading', zip_file.text, '...',)
        r = requests.get(zip_url)
        with open(zip_file.text, 'wb') as zipFile:
            zipFile.write(r.content)


def download_links(root, cat):
    url = ''.join([root, cat])
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

    for zips_suffix in soup.select("a[href*=repaints.php?ac=]"):
        # get_zips(root, zips_suffix['href'])
        next_page = ''.join([root, zips_suffix['href']])
        get_zips(next_page)


link_root = 'http://web.archive.org/web/20041225023002/http://www.projectai.com:80/libraries/'

category = 'acfiles.php?cat=6'
download_links(link_root, category)
```

Comment: Finally got this moved to chat, thank you @samuel-liew